# Internet speed slows down when using NAT on a Raspberry Pi single NIC router

Tags: iptables, raspberry-pi, nat

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B configured as a single NIC router, when i enable NAT via iptables then my internet will slow down by half of the maximum speed (75mbit of 150mbit) when I turn the NAT in iptables off, it will instantly go back to 150mbit. What am i doing wrong?

My thanks in advance.

Michel

Comment: extra note: I need the NAT in iptables for the iptables to work. maybe i can use something other than NAT, i dont see why i need NAT to to get an iptables script to work.  also im using a gigabit usb adapter, the raspberry is using usb2 but that should not limit the 150mbit, i have tested this (If i plug an usb drive in i get 240mbit read speeds.)

Comment: When NAT is handled in software, it will slow you down. That is one reason Cisco won't do NAT on its switches, only its routers; the routers have hardware to handle NAT that the switches do not.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out, i can use FORWARD rules instead of NAT rules. A second NAT is bad practise in my case i think.

Comment: I thought it was worth mentioning [this article](https://atoonk.medium.com/linux-kernel-and-measuring-network-throughput-547c3b68c4d2) that mentions a huge performance loss (like 75% reduction) when running SNAT rules with the linux kernel. A comment on the original answer mentions that software NAT slows things down; a Pi will especially fall victim to this. Oh well!